# Why does the open() function raise a PermissionError instead of a IsADirectoryError when opening a directory?

Tags: python

For some reason, when i try to `open()` a directory, it raises `PermissionError` instead of `IsADirectoryError` on Windows 10.

Even when i run Python as Administrator!

```py
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, ctypes
>>> bool(ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin())
True # This means python is run as administrator (not required)
>>> os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Allearthstuffs")
>>> with open("Downloads") as f:
...    pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Downloads'
```

The reason i want `open()` to raise `PermissionError` instead of `IsADirectoryError` is because of `try` blocks . . .

```py
fn = input("Enter filename: ")

try:
    with open(fn) as f:
        fc = f.read()
except IsADirectoryError:
    print("Requested path is not file!")
except PermissionError: # open() will raise PermissionError, so this except block is triggered . . .
    print("Access denied!")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No such file!")
except OSError:
    print("Invalid filename!")
```

Comment: Linux raises `IsADirectoryError` in this case.  I don't know why Windows does not.

Comment: The Windows designers decided to make directories non-readable. You have to use directory-specific APIs to access the contents, not the normal file API.

Comment: What's the value of the `winerror` attribute of the exception?